# Файл настроек работает некорректно

Tags: c#, wpf

Приветствую!

Не могу понять как работает файл настроек. Уже всю голову сломал. Итак, есть WPF приложение с файлом настроек. Он нужен что бы 1 раз при первом запуске показать сообщение с условиями пользования в программе. По умолчанию оно `False` Если пользователь их принимает то меняется на `True` если нет то программа просто закрывается и ничего не происходит и так пока пользователь не примет условия. И более при запуске окно показывать не нужно. Файл настроек создаю так : ПКМ по решению => Добавить => Создать элемент => Общие => Файл настроек (Settings1.settings). Добавляю булевское поле `DisclaimerAccept` со значение `False` :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее при запуске программы :

```
        if (Settings1.Default.DisclaimerAccept == false)
        {
            Disclaimer disclamer = new Disclaimer();
            disclamer.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            disclamer.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Далее начинается магия. Когда я запускаю - окна не появляется а во время дебага `DisclaimerAccept` показывает `True`! При этом даже в app.config это значение ложь :

```
<userSettings>
<Myproject.Settings1>
  <setting name="DisclaimerAccept" serializeAs="Binary">
    <value>False</value>
  </setting>
 </Myproject.Settings1>
</userSettings>
```

UPD Сохранение настроек (если пользователь принял условия)

```
    private void AcceptDisclaimer_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings1.Default.DisclaimerAccept = true;
        Settings1.Default.Save();
        this.Close();  
    }
```

Не понимаю почему так происходит. Буду рад любой помощи или подсказке.

Comment: @Birdy добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Birdy неважно как я запущу exe - с отладчиком, без или через установщик - результат все равно один.

Comment: Да поймите вы что когда пере собираете проект, файл настроек снова будет сброшен как был записан вами в режиме дизайнера. Очень важно что бы вы запустили его 2 раза без отладчика, и собрав 1 раз.

Comment: @Birdy перечитайте внимательно. Файл настроек и должен быть сброшен в false но при запуске он true.зачем мне запускать его 2 раза? Если при первом запуске должно быть false и показаны условия и только если я приму их то настройка станет true и больше не будет выводится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы выбрали "Пользователь", значит настройка будет храниться отдельно для каждого  пользователя, и не в файле app.config приложения. Ведь несколько пользователей могут запускать приложение из одной папки, а настройки для них будут разные.

Возможные места, где может находиться файл с настройками:

> C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\ApplicationName
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\ApplicationName
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ApplicationName

Соответственно, у вас все работает как надо, однажды вы галочку поставили и больше сообщение не вылазит. Если вы хотите отдельную логику для отладки, рекомендую использовать директиву `#if DEBUG`

Comment: А если поставить в конструкторе не "Пользователь" а "Приложение" то невозможно принудительно поменять настройку `доступ только для чтения`

Comment: @Сергей настройки приложения задаются один раз до запуска и не меняются, настройки пользователя можно менять

Comment: @RusArt понятно, спасибо. сейчас попробую

Answer (score 1):

Откройте ваш файл `App.xaml.cs` и перегрузите метод `OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)`.

Далее добавьте ту да следующий код.

```
// В режиме дебага будем сбрасывать настройки на по умолчанию как было написано в режиме дизайнера
#if DEBUG
if(Settings1.Default.DisclaimerAccept)
{
    Settings1.Default.DisclaimerAccept = false;
    Settings1.Default.Save();
}
#endif
```

После можете менять его сколько угодно (в режиме отладки), при каждом выходе из программы он будет сбрасываться на указанные в дизайнере.

Comment: Зачем мне специально сбрасывать их, если я их НЕ меняю?

Comment: Прочитайте еще раз вопрос. - `Если пользователь их принимает то меняется на True если нет то программа просто закрывается и ничего не происходит и так пока пользователь не примет условия.`